# How to Export Strava Club activities to an excel?

Tags: strava

How to Export Strava Club activities  (for all Club members) to excel?

Options are available for  exporting self data but not Participant data for a Strava Club.

Answer (score 0):

Its always a big challenge. There is Strava Clubs Reports Google Chrome extension, which helps a lot.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/strava-clubs-reports/lgflepkbehloedhbiajhlaecldnijpjd

It fetches activities which are sync during a interval of hours (Pages / number of activities limits)

Later, you can export it into .csv format which gets open easily in excel.

I am working since last year, have to do that process almost every 1-2 hours.

There is duplication of repeat syncs and therefore some process therefore to do at end of day to have unique data.

Hope this may help you in some way.

Comment: Thanks. Are you referring to this one? https://www.crx4chrome.com/extensions/lgflepkbehloedhbiajhlaecldnijpjd/

Comment: @da_elixir Official website is https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/strava-clubs-reports/lgflepkbehloedhbiajhlaecldnijpjd

Comment: Thanks. I did try this, but it does not exclusively pick up the Strava Club data. It only collects the data for the folks you follow and are listed on the wall.

Comment: No you have to goto first to Recent Activities and then click on reports.
It fetches that periods around 100-200 activities saved.
This you have to repeat every hour or regular interval to fetch if saved anyone later.

Yes, for safer side you can follow all the club members, and request the athletes who have privacy kept to follow same back. So that even if privacy settings are kept by any athlete that data is also fetched. Or else everyone should have to keep privacy settings to everyone.